# Multiple Table join - Time consuming

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to excute the below query in MS SQL sever and it
's taking huge time
For just top 10 rows it's taking more time and without top 10 command it took time upto an hour still didn't gave me result.
Basically, what i'm trying to do here is to get count of medals. I've tables as below mentioned
Countries - 2 Columns - NOC and Region
One table for each type of medal with other columns and NOC is common key.

```
SELECT 
top 10 
C.NOC,C.Region,Count(Gold.Medal) as TotalGM, 
Count(Silver.Medal) as TotalSM,Count(Bronze.Medal) as TotalBM 
FROM Countries C
LEFT JOIN Gold ON C.NOC= Gold.NOC
LEFT JOIN Silver ON C.NOC= Silver.NOC
LEFT JOIN Bronze ON C.NOC=Bronze.NOC
GROUP BY C.NOC,C.Region
```

What could've gone wrong here or is there any other method to do it? How it can be optimized. Kindly help me here.

Comment: Are you shure you are not creating a cartesian product? Can you please add the relations between the tables too.

Comment: Seems like the problem is more the design; rather than having a column for each medal type (Gold, Silver and Bronze), the type should be a column in a `Medal` table.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed, but it doesn't explain why it is taking so long.

Comment: How many rows are there in each table?

Comment: What `INDEX`s do you have?

Comment: Because the OP is likely created a cartesian join, as Martin suggests, @PaulSinnema . If, for example, a country has 10 gold medals, 20 silver, and 30 bronze, the above will likely result in **6,000** rows for that country alone.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'd guess that `NOC` is [National Olympic Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Olympic_Committee), based on that they are using medals, but as multiple countries are part of a single NOC, this might mean that the cartesian `JOIN`s are even worse. Perhaps every country in the European Olympic Committees (EOC) is `JOIN`ing to every country's medals in the EOC; considering there's 50 countries in the EOC that's going to generate a mess of data... I wouldn't be surprised if such a query takes ages to run, and produces *very* wrong data if the guess it right.

Comment: It's not a cartisian product

Comment: Then give us some sample data, @MANOHARN , in a **consumable** format. I see no way the above can't result in cartesian joins unless the columns and tables are both poorly named and not representative of what that are actually called.

Comment: I'm guessing you changed your query before posting here. As posted this query can't possibly work. You didn't alias Gold_Medal as Gold, etc. We need sample data, table definitions, and your actual query you tried.

Comment: @PaulSinnema countries table has almost 250 entries, Gold, silver and Bronze tables have nearly 14k entries each.

Comment: You also have top 10 but no order by so you have no way of knowing what rows you will get back.

Comment: @MANOHARN I still think you have a Cartesian product. Show us the table definitions please.

Comment: At a guess your might be better off here with 3 separate correlated subqueries instead of outer-joins.

Comment: yeah definite cartesian product here. From the information given each NOC has on average 56 rows per medal table so that will expand out to 175,616 per NOC when the three tables are joined. Some NOC will presumably have many more medals than others and these will be much worse. With this data model you would need to do the aggregation for each medal table by `NOC` first and then join the aggregated results or just UNION ALL the medal tables and get it into the format Larnu suggest and aggregate that and join that onto countries

Comment: I suspect you have a set up like this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05c1036ef7ec259ae17c744aa258553e). Hopefully you can see just how very wrong those results are, and the cartesian product. Even if you `JOIN` on `CountryName`, the whole thing is still *very* wrong: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80d03940dc10a3086c0301a644f5ad5f)

Comment: @Larnu - I think NOC = Country is basically correct. The NOC are things like " Great Britain" not the continental Olympic association groupings

Comment: You're right, I misread the article, @MartinSmith , though that still results in very wrong data (as shown in the second fiddle) (or this one: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd979b55fff77d0827364f9d7b5cfd35)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your protestations you are getting cartesian joins within each NOC.

If [an NOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_at_the_Olympics) has 1,173 gold medals, 953  silver medals and 833 bronze medals then your current query would generate 931,184,877 rows for just that NOC and then collapse them down and generate an incorrect count.

I'd probably write the query as follows.

```
WITH Medals(Class, NOC) As
(
SELECT 'G', NOC
FROM Gold
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S', NOC
FROM Silver
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', NOC
FROM Bronze
), AggMedals AS
(
SELECT 
    NOC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Class = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalGM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Class = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalSM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Class = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalBM
FROM Medals
GROUP BY NOC
)
SELECT *
FROM Countries C
LEFT JOIN AggMedals AM ON AM.NOC = C.NOC
```

you could also do individual `group by NOC` on all three medal tables (in a CTE or with derived tables) and then left join your country table onto those results.

Answer (score 0):

I got the required output finally by using below query.

````
SELECT C.NOC,
C.Region,
G.Total_GM,
S.Total_SM,
B.Total_BM from Countries C
LEFT JOIN (SELECT NOC,Count(Medal) as Total_GM from Gold
           Group by NOC) G
ON C.NOC = G.NOC
LEFT JOIN (Select NOC,Count(Medal) as Total_SM from Silver
           Group by NOC) S
ON C.NOC = S.NOC
LEFT JOIN (SELECT NOC,Count(Medal) as Total_BM from Bronze
           Group by NOC) B
ON C.NOC = B.NOC
Order by Total_GM desc, Total_SM desc, Total_BM desc;```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).